# Return All Values of Column A and Put them in Column B until Specific Value Is reached

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am still having trouble with with this and nothing seems to work for me. I have a data frame with two columns. I am trying to return all of the values in column A in a new column, B. However, I want to loop through column A and stop returning those values  and instead return 0 when the cumulative sum reaches 8 or the next value would make it greater than 8.

```
    df    max_val = 8

    A
    1
    2
    2
    3 
    4
    5
    1
```

The output should look something like this

```
    df    max_val = 8

    A    B
    1    1
    2    2
    2    2
    3    3
    4    0
    5    0
    1    0
```

I thought something like this

```
    def func(x):
        if df['A'].cumsum() <= max_val:
            return x
        else:
          return 0
```

This doesn't work:

```
     df['B'] = df['A'].apply(func, axis =1 )
```

Neither does this:

```
     df['B'] = func(df['A'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1** One approach using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
df['B']= np.where((df.A.cumsum()<=max_val), df.A ,0)
```

Sample output -

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  0
5  5  0
6  1  0
```

---

**Approach #2** Another using `array-initialization` -

```
def app2(df,max_val):
    a = df.A.values
    colB = np.zeros(df.shape[0],dtype=a.dtype)
    idx = np.searchsorted(a.cumsum(),max_val, 'right')
    colB[:idx] = a[:idx]
    df['B'] = colB
```

---

**Runtime test**

Seems like [@jezrael's `pd.where` based one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281341/3293881) is close one, so timing against it on a bigger dataset -

```
In [293]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0,9,(1000000))})

In [294]: max_val = 1000000

# @jezrael's soln
In [295]: %timeit df['B1'] = df['A'].where(df['A'].cumsum() <= max_val, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.22 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [296]: %timeit df['B2']= np.where((df.A.cumsum()<=max_val), df.A ,0)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.45 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [297]: %timeit app2(df, max_val)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.47 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].where(df['A'].cumsum() <= max_val, 0)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  0
5  5  0
6  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['B']=[x if x<=8 else 0 for x in df['A'].cumsum()]
df
Out[7]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  3
2  2  5
3  3  8
4  4  0
5  5  0
6  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add values to a variable like this :

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if A<max_val:
        return x
    else:
        return 0
    A=A+df[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting in multiple lines

```
import pandas as pd
A=[1,2,2,3,4,5,1]
MAXVAL=8
df=pd.DataFrame(data=A,columns=['A'])
df['cumsumA']=df['A'].cumsum()
df['B']=df['cumsumA']*(df['cumsumA']<MAXVAL).astype(int)
```

You can then drop the 'cumsumA' column

Answer (score 0):

The below will work fine -

```
import numpy as np
max_val = 8
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].cumsum() <= max_val , df['A'],0)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just a way to do it with `.loc`:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].cumsum()
df['b'] = df['a']
df['b'].loc[df['c'] > 8] = 0
```